# Manga where the main character has a luck special power. Uses it to get rich

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character has a skill or power to see the chances of things, like which ticket wins the lottery. He wins and also helps the store clerk sell his house, then a dog almost runs into him but he evades the dog and gives it back to its owner (the female character in the story).

Later on he helps save the live of another girl that's important but falls on his head and the system shuts down to save his life. He comes back later
for more information and goes to a kind of stone market where he asks the system which stones have gems in it and makes so a bunch of money. He was poor before.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names or the distinctive appearance of any of the characters?

Comment: Sadly no thats why i asked it here i also googled "chance system" but i cant find anything

Comment: "thats the female charachter in the story later" - do you mean the (romantic) female lead of the story? Was this in full color or black and white?

Comment: Yes and in full color

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was the main character's name? Where did you read this? How did he see the chances (e.g. was it floating in numbers above the object or what)? Was this aimed at adults (with sex/nudity/gore/violence) or a more general audience? What was the dog's name? What was the girl's name? What was the setting (medieval/fantasy/urban)? Who did the clerk sell his house to? Were there literal lottery tickets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the manga. It was "[*I Can See The Success Rate*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-can-see-the-success-rate)"

> Bai Wu, who is frustrated with his life in the real world, suddenly
> gains the ability to see the success rate of events. Use the success
> rate to reach the pinnacle of life!
>
> [image]

Comment: Well done on locating this yourself. It's best not to link to websites that post unlicenced manga though.